# Слушатель на текстуру/кнопку

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Добрый день, копался в гугле и так и не понял, как мне поставить слушатель на текстуру или просто сделать кнопку(с текстурой) и при нажатии на неё совершать действия.

P.S есть нормальная русскоязычная документация по libgdx?

Comment: а чем не угодила оригинальная документация?

Answer (score 0):

Если в двух словах то можно так:

```
    boolean touch;
    Sprite sprite = new Sprite(new Texture("file.jpg"));
    Rectangle buttonBounding = sprite.getBoundingRectangle();
    Vector2 mouse = new Vector2();

    mouse.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - Gdx.input.getY());
    if (buttonBounding.contains(mouse)) {
        touch = true;
    } else {
        touch = false;
    }
```

Y - переворачиваем если координаты экранные.